# Tengo errores al utilizar jQuery en un client.js externo

Tags: javascript, jquery, script

Estoy queriendo implementar un client.js de la siguiente manera:

Sucede que tengo el siguiente error en chrome:

```
jquery.min.js:2 Uncaught TypeError: e.indexOf is not a function
    at w.fn.init.w.fn.load (jquery.min.js:2)
    at waypoints.min.js:8
    at waypoints.min.js:8
    at waypoints.min.js:8
    at waypoints.min.js:8
```

Lo estoy trabajando de la siguiente manera

**index.html:**

```
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src='http://localhost:3000/js/client.js'></script>
```

**client.js:**

La idea de la función es colocar `<script>` detrás de la declaración de mi script.

```
function initialize(callback) {
      // Capturo el script
      let firstNode = document.querySelector('script[src$="http://localhost:3000/javascripts/client.js"]');
      // Genero nuevos scripts
      let vue = document.createElement('script');
      let socketIo = document.createElement('script');

      vue.src = 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/vue/latest/vue.min.js';
      socketIo.src = 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/2.0.3/socket.io.js';

      // Los agrego antes de la declaración de mi script.
      document.body.insertBefore(botui, firstNode);
      document.body.insertBefore(vue, botui);
      document.body.insertBefore(socketIo, vue);

      return callback;
    }
```

La función *initialize* dispara la ejecución del código restante...

Aclaro: **No estoy usando**  `$( window ).on( "load", function() { ... })` . Tampoco pretendo usarlo.

Agradecería la ayuda,

Saludos.

Comment: El _src_ de tu script y de _querySelector_ no coinciden, además, creo que sobra el `$`.

Comment: Ya lo corregí, fue un error al escribir el post. Igualmente sigo con el error